# How do I merge multiple lists into one list?

Tags: python, list, merge

I have many lists:

```
['it']
['was']
['annoying']
```

I want to merge those into a single list:

```
['it', 'was', 'annoying']
```

Answer (score 240):

```
import itertools
ab = itertools.chain(['it'], ['was'], ['annoying'])
list(ab)
```

Just another method....

Comment: Ok there is a file which has different words in 'em. I have done s = [word] to put each word of the file in list. But it creates separate lists (print s returns ['it]']['was']['annoying']) as I mentioned above. I want to merge all of them in one list.

Comment: @user1452759 `list(itertools.chain(['it'], ['was'], ['annoying']))` gives `['it', 'was', 'annnoying']`. Is that different from what you want?

Comment: ... or looking for "list.extend", if already have it wrapped in a list.

Comment: maybe he was trying to pass a list: L=[['it'], ['was'], ['annoying']] and call  itertools.chain(L). That doesn't work.

In order to use this solution properly he should use: itertools.chain(*L)

Comment: If the input is a list of lists, using the `from_iterable` function such as `ab = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([['it'], ['was'], ['annoying']]))` would be give the answer the OP expects

Comment: You could also pass it as an `*args` by saying: `itertools.chain(*my_list_of_lists)`.

Comment: Kinda makes `chain.from_iterable` pointless doesn't it?

Comment: @BallpointBen No, because `from_iterable` it accepts any iterable, which can be e.g. generator returning subsequent lists.

Answer (score 184):

Just add them:

```
['it'] + ['was'] + ['annoying']
```

You should read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) to learn basic info like this.

Comment: You solved the i=3 case, how about i=n?

Comment: @Full Decent, thanks for point this out, did not think about that i=n case. But I think if it is i=n case, can loop in the lists and concatenate them. For me, just need the most comma way to join 2 lists without duplication elements.

Comment: @zhihong Hey there, it's been well over a full year but you can use something like `mylist = list(set(mylist))` after merging lists to get rid of the duplicates.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem for i = n using the "flatten a list of lists" approach in the "Possible duplicate" list

Comment: @WilliamEntriken , Technically you can use build in sum for example `sum(mylist, [])` but it is not very optimize.

Comment: For the i=n, you can do this:

Comment: For i=n case, you can also use `reduce(lambda l1, l2: l1+l2, lists)` where `lists` is a list or a tuple of the lists.

Answer (score 64):

```
a = ['it']
b = ['was']
c = ['annoying']

a.extend(b)
a.extend(c)

# a now equals ['it', 'was', 'annoying']
```

Comment: Yes, But if you are not sure about the length of the list (which is to be used to extend the main list) then how am I going to extend ? Is it anyway possible to use slicing method to deal with variable length lists ?