# How to merge three list to one and keeping same key

Tags: python-3.x

I have list1, list2 and list3 and I wnat to merge them to a single array without changing their key

I checked stackoverflow and python.org

```
list1 =[1,2,3]
list2=[4,5,6]
list3=[7,8,9]



final_expected_result =[[1,4,7],[4,5,8],[3,6,9]]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge multiple lists into one list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574195/how-to-merge-multiple-lists-into-one-list-in-python)

Comment: what do you mean by *"merge"* and *"keep their key"*?

Comment: Otherwise, you can create a fourth list and add each of your three lists to the fourth list.

Comment: `final_expected_result = [list1, list2, list3]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `zip` is what you're looking for. `zip` does return an iterable object, so you'll likely want to convert it to a list.

```py
>>> list(zip(list1, list2, list3))
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

If you're set on having a list of lists instead of a list of tuples integrate a `map` into the expression.

```py
>>> list(map(list, zip(list1, list2, list3)))
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: what's the point of zipping lists and converting back to `list`? That would just "cut" all lists to the length of the shortest list. `zip` could more likely be useful if you e.g. want to `for a,b,c in zip(list1, list2, list3):`

Comment: @MrFuppes, I entirely agree. However, I've made a point of matching my output to the output specified by OP. Otherwise I wouldn't have bothered with the `map` either.

Comment: it's alright, I'm not even sure what he's asking for exactly.