# Open and read all binary files from directory an output to lists - Python

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm trying to output the entire contents of multiple .pkt files, containing binary data, as a series of hexadecimal lists: (Adapted from [How to open every file in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262293/))

```
import glob
path = 'filepath'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.pkt')):    
   with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename), 'rb') as f:
   pair_hex = ["{:02x}".format(c) for c in f.read()]
   print(pair_hex)
```

Which outputs:

```
['09', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '0b', '09']
['09', '04', 'bb']
['09', 'bb']
['bb']
['09', '04', '0b', '09']
```

That makes sense, because i'm looping through the files, but what I need is:

```
[['09', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '0b', '09'],['09', '04', 'bb'],['09', 'bb'],['bb'],['09', '04', '0b', '09']]
```

So I can manipulate all the data.

I have tried to apply `append()`, `"".join()`, `map()` as well as the advice at [How to merge multiple lists into one list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574195/), but nothing changes the output. How can I get the desired list of lists?

Comment: Put the code in a function, and then apply the advice needed to `return` the list of lists after creating it in the loop. Alternately, use a *list comprehension* to process the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

untested but try

```
import glob, os
path = 'filepath'
ret = []
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.pkt')):    
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename), 'rb') as f:
        pair_hex = ["{:02x}".format(c) for c in f.read()]
        ret.append(pair_hex)

print(ret)
```

the above prints the following on my console which is the same as your "desired output"

```
[['09', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '0b', '09'], ['09', '04', 'bb'], ['09', 'bb'], ['bb'], ['09', '04', '0b', '09']]
```

and this is what I used to create the .pkt files on my machine with `out` set to a copy--paste of your "desired output"

```
out = [['09', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '0b', '09'],['09', '04', 'bb'],['09', 'bb'],['bb'],['09', '04', '0b', '09']]

for i, a in enumerate(out):
    with open(f"{i}.pkt", 'w') as f:
        f.write(''.join(map(lambda s: chr(int(s, 16)), a)))
```

Comment: This leads to a loop of where each list size is multiplied by the number of files, which is 19. So it leads to 1*2*3*...*19.  I tried to place ret [] within the loop, but this results in the same as above.

Comment: This only nests the list further [['09','03']] [['01',02']] etc. They're still not all in the same list i.e. [['09','03'], ['01',02']]

Comment: Then I give up; my earlier answer had it all in one list but you said that's not what you wanted.

Comment: No sorry, it looped!
x1 ['09', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '0b', '09']

x2 ['09', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '0b', '09']
['09', '04', 'bb']

x3['09', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '0b', '09']
['09', '04', 'bb']
['09', 'bb']

x4['09', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '0b', '09']
['09', '04', 'bb']
['09', 'bb']
['bb']     .I only want each list displayed once, as shown above?

Comment: brought it back to my original answer and after creating some .pkt files, this prints the "desired output" in your question

Comment: Correct you are! No sure what happened with my first implementation, but thanks a lot Justin.