# How to merge three arrays?

Tags: python, pandas

My dataset consists of three columns, I required to merge the data into one column. For example, if 1, 2, and 3 are the first entries of each column the merged column should be 123. I attempted to solve this problem with concatenate command but it is not useful. Here is my script:

```
tr = pd.read_csv("YMD.txt", sep='\t',header=None)

Y = tr[0]
M = tr[1]
D = tr[2]
np.concatenate((Y, M, D))
```

Comment: Please add some of the content of `YMD.txt` to your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge multiple lists into one list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574195/how-to-merge-multiple-lists-into-one-list-in-python)

Comment: You actually mean *"string concatenate"* not *"merge"*. cc: @AlexeyNikonov. In your example with 1,2,3 do you want the integer 123 or the string '123'?

Comment: integer 1, 2, 3 not string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need Pandas or Numpy to read a tab-delimited file and merge the first 3 columns into a new list:

```
ymd = []
with open("YMD.txt") as f:
    for row in f:
        row = row.strip().split("\t")
        ymd.append("".join(row[:3]))
print(ymd)
```