# Writing a function to merge 2 lists...maybe more

Tags: python, list, concatenation

New to python... I am trying to write a function `merge()` to take two lists and combine them, and then I would like to expand that to an `n` number of lists.

The output I get from this code is only the `grapes` list and not concatenated with the `apples` list.

**Failed Attempt with my fuction:**

```
grapes = ['purple', 'red']
apples = ['green', 'yellow', 'orange']

def merge():
    ''' merge the lists '''
    for i in apples:
        grapes.append(i)
print("Concatenated list: " + str(grapes))

merge()
```

**Output :**

`Concatenated list: ['purple', 'red']`

Thank you for the read...

Comment: Well in your current case, you are outputting `grapes` before you're calling `merge`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I concatenate two lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-do-i-concatenate-two-lists-in-python)

Comment: That's also worth checking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574195/how-to-merge-multiple-lists-into-one-list-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You should first call merge() before outputing grapes

I mean :

```
grapes = ['purple', 'red']
apples = ['green', 'yellow', 'orange']

def merge():
    ''' merge the lists '''
    for i in apples:
        grapes.append(i)

merge()
print("Concatenated list: " + str(grapes))
```

Or you could just do:

```
fruits = grapes + apples
print(fruits)
```

Comment: I was specifically trying to write a function for this than manual concatenation, Thankyou for your answer!

Comment: Please read [answer], and don't answer questions that boil down to simple typos or which are common duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
array1 = ["a" , "b" , "c" , "d"]
array = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5]

def merge(*array_list):
  output_array = []
  for array in array_list:
    output_array = output_array + array
  return output_array

merged_array = merge(array1 , array2)
```

Hope it helps :)