# How to combine two list from a single txt file

Tags: python

I have a txt file that has lists inside.

```
['livhu','clean','today']
['livhu','cook','tomorrow']
```

When I use this code attached.

My output is:

```
['livhu','clean','today']
['livhu','clean','today', 'livhu','cook','tomorrow']
```

[The code Im using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMwuy.png)

I expected the output to be:

```
['livhu','clean','today', 'livhu','cook','tomorrow']
```

Comment: Please include the actual code in your question instead of a picture of it.  The exact actual content of the file would be useful too, if what you posted isn't it -- since you didn't post the actual code I can't run it quickly to make sure, but I'd expect the output to be a little bit "rougher" if you put pseudo-JSON into the file and tried to parse it with `str.split()`.

Comment: Note that the ***string*** `"['livhu','clean','today']"` is different from the ***list*** `['livhu','clean','today']`.  Do you have control over the process that is writing your `.txt` file?  If so, I recommend writing the values in a format that is easier to parse, like CSV or JSON.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I merge multiple lists into one list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574195/how-do-i-merge-multiple-lists-into-one-list)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change **append** to **extend**

```
user_lists.extend(user_list)
```

If that does not help, try to also comment (#) the string above (user_list = " ".join...)

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
l = [ eval(item) for item in s.split(' ') ]
```

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` would be a lot safer than the regular `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are reading a text like

```
txt = "['livhu','clean','today'] ['livhu','cook','tomorrow']"
```

you can parse it into two lists using this code

```
txt1, txt2 = txt.split()
```

The output will be...

```
print(txt1)
>> "['livhu','clean','today']"

print(txt2)
>> "['livhu','cook','tomorrow']"
```

note that the output still a string
to convert it into list of strings you can use function like this

```
def convert_to_list(string:str) -> list:
    string = string.replace("[", "").replace("]", "") # to replace square brackets "[" and "]"
    string = string.replace("'", "") # to replace the single quotes '
    return [i for i in string.split(",")]
```

you can use this function as follow..

```
li1 = convert_to_list(txt1)
li2 = convert_to_list(txt2)
```

the output will be..

```
print(li1)
>> ['livhu','clean','today']

print(li2)
>> ['livhu','cook','tomorrow']
```

finally you can combine them into one list using this code

```
li = list1 + list2
```

The output will be

```
print(li)
>> ['livhu','clean','today','livhu','cook','tomorrow']
```

but note that there is assumption here as we assume that the text will contain one space, if there is more spaces you will need more variables to unpack the text.

Comment: converion only work of list of string with no string having `[` or `]` character except from first and last . just do exec(stirng) that's better, save that in object

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe want a `unique output` as a result.
You can try a merging the `list` then `cast` it to a `set` then `cast` the results back again to a `list`.
Try this:

```py
list1 = ['livhu','clean','today']
list2 = ['livhu','cook','tomorrow']
combined = list(set(list1 + list2))
print(combined)
```

```bash
>>> ['today', 'clean', 'livhu', 'tomorrow', 'cook']
```

From your code, you can `cast` `user_list` to a `set` to get unique values, then `cast` it back again to a `list`:

```py
user_list = list(set(user_list))
```